# `UIViewControllerRepresentable` table view disappears after long tap

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swift-composable-architecture

I have a `UIViewControllerRepresentable` wrapper for `UITableViewController` and am using [swift composable architecture](https://github.com/pointfreeco/swift-composable-architecture), which is probably irrelevant to the issue.

Here's my table view wrapper code, including the context menu code (I have omitted quite a lot of setup code):

```
public struct List<EachState, EachAction, RowContent, RowPreview, Destination, Data, ID>: UIViewControllerRepresentable, KeyPathUpdateable
    where Data: Collection, RowContent: View, RowPreview: View, Destination: View, EachState: Identifiable, EachState.ID == ID {

    private var actionProvider: (IndexSet) -> UIMenu? = { _ in nil }
    private var previewProvider: (Store<EachState, EachAction>) -> RowPreview? = { _ in nil }

    // setup code

    public func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UITableViewController {
        let tableViewController = UITableViewController()
        tableViewController.tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableViewController.tableView.dataSource = context.coordinator
        tableViewController.tableView.delegate = context.coordinator
        tableViewController.tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        tableViewController.tableView.register(HostingCell<RowContent>.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        return tableViewController
    }

    public func updateUIViewController(_ controller: UITableViewController, context: Context) {
        context.coordinator.rows = data.enumerated().map { offset, item in
            store.scope(state: { $0[safe: offset] ?? item },
                        action: { (item.id, $0) })
        }
        controller.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    public func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(rows: [],
                    content: content,
                    onDelete: onDelete,
                    actionProvider: actionProvider,
                    previewProvider: previewProvider,
                    destination: destination)
    }

    public func previewProvider(_ provider: @escaping (Store<EachState, EachAction>) -> RowPreview?) -> Self {
        update(\.previewProvider, value: provider)
    }

    public func destination(_ provider: @escaping (Store<EachState, EachAction>) -> Destination?) -> Self {
        update(\.destination, value: provider)
    }

    public class Coordinator: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

        fileprivate var rows: [Store<EachState, EachAction>]
        private var content: (Store<EachState, EachAction>) -> RowContent
        private var actionProvider: (IndexSet) -> UIMenu?
        private var previewProvider: (Store<EachState, EachAction>) -> RowPreview?

        public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            rows.count
        }

        public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            guard let tableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as? HostingCell<RowContent>,
                  let view = rows[safe: indexPath.row] else {
                return UITableViewCell()
            }

            tableViewCell.setup(with: content(view))

            return tableViewCell
        }

        public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            if editingStyle == .delete {
                onDelete(IndexSet(integer: indexPath.item))
            }
        }

        public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, contextMenuConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, point: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {
            guard let store = rows[safe: indexPath.row] else { return nil }

            return UIContextMenuConfiguration(
                identifier: nil,
                previewProvider: {
                    guard let preview = self.previewProvider(store) else { return nil }
                    let hosting = UIHostingController<RowPreview>(rootView: preview)
                    return hosting
                },
                actionProvider: { _ in
                    self.actionProvider(IndexSet(integer: indexPath.item))
            })
        }
    }
}
```

```
private class HostingCell<Content: View>: UITableViewCell {
    var host: UIHostingController<Content>?

    func setup(with view: Content) {
        if host == nil {
            let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: view)
            host = controller

            guard let content = controller.view else { return }
            content.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            contentView.addSubview(content)

            content.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
            content.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
            content.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
            content.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        } else {
            host?.rootView = view
        }
        setNeedsLayout()
    }
}
```

And here's an example usage:

```
private struct ClassView: View {
    let store = Store<ClassState, ClassAction>(
        initialState: ClassState(),
        reducer: classReducer,
        environment: ClassEnv()
    )

    var body: some View {
        WithViewStore(store) { viewStore in
            CoreInterface.List(store.scope(state: \.people, action: ClassAction.personAction)) { store in
                PersonView(store: store)
            }
            .actionProvider { indices in
                let delete = UIAction(title: "Delete", image: UIImage(systemName: "trash"), attributes: .destructive) { _ in
                    viewStore.send(.remove(indices))
                }

                return UIMenu(title: "", children: [delete])
            }
            .previewProvider { viewStore in
                Text("preview")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is as follows: when I long tap on a cell to show the context menu, then dismiss it and scroll up, the table view disappears. This only happens when it's inside a `NavigationView`. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hC0G.gif) is a short video of the issue.

The project is on [github](https://github.com/smeshko/workout_timer). The table view wrapper is in `InternalFrameworks/Core/CoreInterface/Views/List`, usage is in `InternalFrameworks/Screens/QuickWorkoutsList/Source/QuickWorkoutsList`. In order to run the project, you'll need [xcodegen](https://github.com/yonaskolb/XcodeGen). Run

`brew install xcodegen`
`xcodegen generate`

Comment: It is hardly possible to say something without debugging. Would you provide access to project?

Comment: I added a link to the github repo and some explanations.

Comment: I wanted to help you solve this, but I see you've updated the project to iOS 15 which is still in beta. So I can't compile and run it, since the third-party packages are running beta software as well. Surely you can post a version that uses released software, since you reported this last November...? If you can provide me with the version of QuickWorkoutsList you were using last november I can build, run and debug the project.

Comment: CoreLogic, CorePersistance, DomainEntities also refuse to build. QuickWorkoutForm, RunningTimer and WorkoutSettings won't build as a result of the previous errors.